# SSRS 2008 R2 - Resetting the runningvalue when a specific row is returned

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that returns sales data. The report has a quantity column and a running total column that i calculate by using the SSRS Running Value.

E.G.:

```
=RunningValue(Iif(Fields!iType.Value = 6, 0, Fields!iQuantity.Value), Sum, Nothing)
```

I am trying to reset this running value back to the quantity when the iTypeID (transaction type) = 6.

I have tried the switch option, various if statements however i cannot get the outcome i need.

Rather difficult to explain without being able to post a screen shot / image of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this (on a different database and field) and it worked

=IIF(Fields!iType.Value = 6,Fields!iType.Value,RunningValue(Fields!iType.Value, Sum, Nothing))

but it does not start counting from 0 after the value appears.

You could use scope to achieve this, but you will be forced to add at least 1 column to your dataset, and it will not be that easy.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136(v=sql.100).aspx

It might be easier to achieve this within SQL query, depending on the bigger picture, ammount of data etc.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me - the query seems to work to a point, however when a return a row with the TypeID = 6 i need the running total to be the same value as the quantity. The report basically pulls a list of sales and when we do a stock take the running value then needs to be set to what the quantity count was at the time of stock take. Is there a way i can show you a screen shot? Sorry this is my first post on StackOverFlow

Comment: Hi Jacob - have you got any further ideas as to how i could possible resolve this issue?